# Convert numeric Year to string

Tags: ruby

Is there a built-in method in Ruby that converts numeric Year to the string representation?
Example: `"2015"` => `"twentyfifteen"`

I know I can do something like:

```
def numeric_year_to_string(numeric_year)  
  years = {"2015" => "twentyfifteen", "2014" => "twentyfourteen" }
  years.has_key?(numeric_year) ? years[numeric_year] : "twentyfifteen"  
end
```

Comment: You can use [this gem](https://github.com/radar/humanize) to facilitate this task: https://github.com/radar/humanize. It won't do all the work, but it'll help

Comment: Note that in Ruby method names are like `numeric_year_to_string` and not the style you've used there and there's no space between the method name and the opening brace. This helps your code fit in better stylistically with the rest of the Ruby code base.

Comment: @csi: you forgot the space. It's a serious offense! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a gem or extension in Ruby that does this - you will have to write one yourself.

`Humanize` comes the closest - https://github.com/radar/humanize

```
require 'humanize'
```

require 'humanize'

```
def numeric_year_to_string(numeric_year)
  tens = numeric_year%100
  hundreds = (numeric_year - tens) / 100
  return hundreds.humanize + " oh-" + tens.humanize if tens < 10
  hundreds.humanize + " " + tens.humanize
end
```

Try this - it works for most of the cases